# Is $\frac{opt}{c}(1-\epsilon)$ for some constant c >0 considered a PTAS?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, approximation

So I am studying PTAS algorithms. For a maximazation problem the difinition says that an algorithm that has value A , is a ptas if :
$A \geq opt(1-\epsilon) \; ,\forall \epsilon > 0$
(and I guess also $\epsilon < 1$ (?) )

Obviously for any constant $c>0 : opt(1-\epsilon)  \geq \frac{opt}{c}(1-\epsilon)$
So when I proved : $A \geq \frac{opt}{c}(1-\epsilon)$ I proved somethhing weaker.
Can this still be consired a ptas algorithm or the definition strictly wants the approximation factor for maximazation to be at least $(1-\epsilon)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is trivially true for $\epsilon \ge 1$, so you don't need to require that.

That said, the condition $A \ge \frac{\text{opt}}{c} \cdot (1-\varepsilon) \; \forall \varepsilon >0$  is equivalent to $A \ge \text{opt} \cdot (1-\varepsilon') \; \forall \varepsilon' > \frac{c-1}{c}$ since we can relate $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon'$ as follows: $\varepsilon' = (c-1)/c+ \varepsilon/c$.

You must have $c>1$ (otherwise you either fall back to the original definition, or no algorithm can meet the condition), which means that $\frac{c-1}{c} > 0$. Therefore this doesn't meet the definition of PTAS.

Comment: isn't it the opposite (?) : if $\epsilon >1$ the right side of the inequality holds trivially (since it's negative) , doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for spotting that.